# moment is not defined (Angular 8, TS 3)

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

Running Angular 8 and TS 3.  I'm unable to get moment to work even though I'm seeing moment.js in the webpack's files via Dev Tools.  I followed moment's suggestions for TS 2 here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/.  Even if I wait for the page to load and call moment() in the command line in dev tools it fails.

The code trying to use moment is in a route guard, so I put the moment reference (for testing) in the page I'm trying to hit.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Then, my auth guard instantiates an 'AuthenticationHelper' that uses moment:

```
[...]

const authHelper = new AuthenticationHelper();
authHelper.RefreshAccessToken(token, this._tokenStore, this._authenticationService, this._authApiService)
        .catch(err => {
          this._router.navigateByUrl(this._loginUrl);
        })

[...]
```

In a subsequent method call inside RefreshAccessToken:

```
[...] && token.Expiration < moment().unix()
```

Comment: Can you show some code of where you are trying to use it?`

Comment: @xdecdec code added

Comment: Can you try putting your import inside the file where your method calls moment?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  In angular.json, I had to add moment to the scripts array so it was loaded and ready to go.

So in build.options.scripts, add "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"

It should look like

```
"scripts": [
    [...]
    "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
]
```

Comment: This is not the offically intended way to use moment in typescript, since this works via the globally exported moment object. Instead, you'll want to import moment in the exact file where you want to use it.

Answer (score -3):

If es6 modules import wont work, the easy solution is use the old import.

```
var moment = require('moment');
```